# Network error when playing video with Phonegap and Video Player plugin

Tags: android, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to play a video with Phonegap on Android using [this plugin](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.dk/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html).

But I keep getting this error: "There was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/window.plugins.videoPlayer.play('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sARyVV0Eyv8')"

The video is a random Youtube.

I followed all the steps in the plugin's page (above) and I'm trying to hit the video like this:

a href="window.plugins.videoPlayer.play('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sARyVV0Eyv8')" (<> removed here)

But the error is always there. This is the cat log:

```
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286): /watch
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286): java.io.FileNotFoundException:     /watch
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at     android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at     org.apache.cordova.IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse(IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:73)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at org.apache.cordova.IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest(IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient.java:46)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.shouldInterceptRequest(CallbackProxy.java:1111)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.shouldInterceptRequest(BrowserFrame.java:863)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeMouseClick(Native Method)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$6800(WebViewCore.java:57)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewCore.java:1788)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvent(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:689)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.dispatchWebKitEvents(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:639)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher.access$800(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:78)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewInputDispatcher$WebKitHandler.handleMessage(WebViewInputDispatcher.java:1153)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:812)
01-01 15:10:36.554: E/generateWebResourceResponse(2286):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

What am I missing?

EDIT, in response to Simon MacDonald's answer and second comment below:
I'm getting deviceready. 
video.js is in my www folder and referenced from the html like this (including the other js references):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="video.js"></script>
```

My plugin line:

```
<plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
```

Is in assets/www/res/xml/config.xml together with the other phonegap plugins.

I put println and Log.e statements in VideoPlayer.java pluginResult and playVideo, but as far as I can see they aren't getting called.

ONE MORE DETAIL: I'm using cordova-2.2.0.js

Comment: "What am I missing? " A file named /watch  :)

Comment: Well the "/watch" is part of the youtube url. Any advice on how to get the processor to realize that?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not valid. It should be:

```
<a href="javascript:window.plugins.videoPlayer.play('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sARyVV0Eyv8')">Play me</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Simon. But when I try this I get no response at all from the emulator.

Comment: Well that will work if the plugin is setup correctly so double check that you are 1) have the video.js in your html, 2) put the VideoPlayer plugin line in config.xml, 3) are actually getting deviceready event.

Comment: I edited my question with more info but basically yes, all 3 items seem to be in place. Thanks again.

Comment: Then what do you see in adb logcat when you click the anchor?

Comment: hmm, there seems to be something here: when the app starts I get this: 
01-03 06:29:02.356: E/SQLiteLog(797): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-03 06:29:02.356: E/SQLiteLog(797): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) - 
01-03 06:29:03.346: E/Web Console(797): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of null at file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:43
When I click the link nothing happens, and nothing shows up in logcat.

Comment: What is at line 43 of index.js? Cause that is where an error is popping up.

Comment: var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening'); as part of this method:     receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }